# Oracle Loadjava JSch Error Incorrectly Formed Java Binary Class Definition

Tags: java, oracle, jar, jsch, loadjava

I am running into an issue trying to load a jar into Oracle. I downloaded the JSch package to code in java from source forge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/). I then attempted the loadjava command while signed into the database. I got an error and I am not sure what I can do to fix it since I am not the creator of the jar file.

Below is the output:

```
loadjava -user username jsch-0.1.54.jar -v                                                                                                                                  arguments: '-user' 'etl_ops' 'jsch-0.1.54.jar' '-v'

creating : resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

loading  : resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

created  : CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Buffer

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Buffer

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$1

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$1

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$MyPipedInputStream

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$MyPipedInputStream

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$PassiveInputStream

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$PassiveInputStream

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$PassiveOutputStream

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel$PassiveOutputStream

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Channel

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelAgentForwarding

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelAgentForwarding

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelDirectTCPIP

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelDirectTCPIP

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$Config

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$Config

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$ConfigDaemon

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$ConfigDaemon

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$ConfigLHost

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP$ConfigLHost

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelForwardedTCPIP

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSession

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSession

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$1

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$1

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$2

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$2

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$3

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$3

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$Header

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$Header

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$LsEntry

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$LsEntry

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$LsEntrySelector

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$LsEntrySelector

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue$OutOfOrderException

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue$OutOfOrderException

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue$Request

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue$Request

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp$RequestQueue

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSubsystem

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSubsystem

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelX11

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelX11

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Cipher

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Cipher

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/CipherNone

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/CipherNone

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/Compression

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/Compression

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$1

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$1

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$2

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$2

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$Config

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository$Config

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/ConfigRepository

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DH

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DH

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC256

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC256

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC384

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC384

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC521

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHEC521

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHECN

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHECN

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHG1

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHG1

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHG14

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHG14

Error while processing com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX

    Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 5176 but got 5175 bytes)

creating : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX

loading  : class com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX

Error while creating class com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX

    ORA-29509: incorrectly formed Java binary class definition

ORA-06512: at line 1

 

Error while reading jsch-0.1.54.jar

    Exception java.io.IOException: Push back buffer is full

The following operations failed

    class com/jcraft/jsch/DHGEX: creation (createFailed)

exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

Comment: you might want to use a fork of jsch, because jsch-1.54 is pretty old. see https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Comment: are you sure, that you want to create ssh connections triggered by a database? As an architect I would disencourage you from doing that. Use a database as a database and not as a service integration platform.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the JAR file is a zip file that contains the source code (click on the files tab and then select the version you want to download and descend into the file structure where you will find the source archive). Download the source code, compile that and make sure there are no errors and then package your compiled version into a JAR and load that.

Or else just load the source files directly into the database (but it may be easier to load a single JAR than to load multiple Java files).